# Form post data is shown in the post header element

Tags: jsf

I have form where I am entering all the data and on the submit button. I am sending the data for the processing. But what I noticed is that I can edit my post data using Tamper Data Add-on of Firefox and I think it is a Hack. So how can avoid this problem? What I have read is JSF uses default POST to send data, if so then why it is showing data in the Header? Is their any way by which I can control this and encode my post data?

Answer (score 1):

That's just how HTTP works. How else would the client be able to send data to the server? Note that you shouldn't confuse request headers with request body. The POST data appears in the request body, not request headers.

But why would you like to avoid this? The only reasonable reason I can think of is that you're validating input data in the client side (using for example JS) instead of in the server side. You shouldn't be doing this. You should always validate in the server side. You should never trust user input. Utilize the JSF-provided validators such as `required="true"`, `<f:validateLongRange>`, `javax.faces.validator.Validator` and so on as much as possible.

As long as you properly validate on the server side, the client can do whatever it want with the HTTP request and you don't need to worry about the safety (that is, when you trust JSF and your own code). JSF has already builtin prevention against XSS and also CSRF (to a certain degree, this has been improved in 2.1 and 2.2 respectively).

If your *actual* concern is actually the man-in-the-middle attacks, then you should take a look at SSL (HTTPS).

Comment: Actually my problem is related to the data tempering in JSF. Currently i can easily temper my form-POST data before sending for processing. Could you let me know if i can prevent it in JSF?.

Comment: Once again: You Can Not. Why would you? The client is fully free to send whatever data it want to send. Either by a HTML form, or by a Java HTTP client program, or by a PHP script, or by Firefox Tamper Data, or by a Proxy, etc..etc.. This does totally not harm as long as your server side code is robust enough and doesn't trust everything. Anyway, I believe you're more worrying about man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: Yes you are right. If i am doing attack in the middle of the request, then how can i prevent that?. I can prevent user on from enetering invalid data on the form by either using javascript or same i can do it on server side using JSF validators. But what about if i temper data in the middle?. How should i handle this?. I have done following.

Comment: As to the man-in-the-middle attacks, I've already answered that: use HTTPS/SSL. This way information is sent encrypted over the network. As to JavaScript validation: only use it to improve user experience, but do not use it as replacement of server side validation. JavaScript runs entirely at the client side and can be disabled/hacked/spoofed by the enduser. You should always validate on server side as well.

Comment: OK, i think your right i need to implement either HTTPS/SSL in my application. I need to explore HTTPS/SSL. Thanks @BalusC